# iphone apps screen getting clipped on ipad mind

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

I am using `ipad` mini with ios 7 for development. I tried to run an iphone only app on it, but screen is getting clipped from sides. I was expecting windowing effect, but this was unexpected.

Please point me if i am missing something or if it is not possible to correctly run iPhone only app ipad mini

Comment: Did you by mistake set your app to Universal instead of iPhone only? In Summery

Answer (score 0):

In your App code, should modify the split viewcontroller instead of viewcontroller in .xib file. you get answer and can run on ipad

Comment: There is no splitViewcontroller in the app. Moerover things work fine when testing on ipad